# Spring marks request as incorrect while posting data to controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Controller sets empty `team` and fetches all `organizations` then passes this 2 objects to JSP. For some reason form is unable to submit data and results in: 
`400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`. Chrome shows form data being passed:

```
name:Chris Paul Camps
rating:9
organization:com.sprhib.model.Organization@7ebffc91
```

**JSP**

```
 <form:form method="POST" commandName="team" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/team/add.html" class="col-md-4">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="name"><spring:message code="label.name"></spring:message>:</label>
                 <form:input class="form-control" path="name" id="name" />
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rating"><spring:message code="label.rating"></spring:message>:</label>
                <form:input class="form-control" path="rating" id="rating" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="organization"><spring:message code="label.organization"></spring:message>:</label>
                <form:select class="form-control" path="organization" id="organization">
                    <form:option value="" label="- Select -"/>
                    <form:options items="${organizations}" itemLabel="name" />
                </form:select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.add"></spring:message>" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </form:form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addTeamPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("teams/add-team-form");
        modelAndView.addObject("team", new Team());
        modelAndView.addObject("organizations", organizationService.getOrganizations());

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingTeam(@ModelAttribute Team team) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        teamService.addTeam(team);
        String message = "Team was successfully added.";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**Team entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {


    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Integer rating;

    private Set<Member> members;

    private Organization organization;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Organization_id", nullable = false)
    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "team_member", joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Team_id", referencedColumnName= "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Member_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    public Set<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(Set<Member> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

}
```

**Organization entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Set<Team> teams;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "organization")
    public Set<Team> getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }

    public void setTeams(Set<Team> teams) {
        this.teams = teams;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Same error after changing to this:

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="organization" id="organization">
                    <form:option value="" label="- Select -"/>
                    <form:options items="${organizations}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                </form:select>
```

Do I have to have two `@ModelAttribute`s in controller, one for team, other for organization?

**UPDATE2:**

Why `organization` appear to be `null` given this error: `nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.sprhib.model.Team.organization`?

Comment: Should this not be the OrganisationId? organization:com.sprhib.model.Organization@7ebffc91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your controller method to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addingTeam(@ModelAttribute Team team,  BindingResult result) {
```

you've most-likely have binding errors, however since inside your controller you don't have a *BindingResult* that immediately follows the *@ModelAttribute* you get a bad request

Check the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for **Invalid ordering of BindingResult** and @ModelAttribute.

> The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object
>   that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have
>   more that one model

I recon that by adding the BindingResult you will get more insight into the exact property that is failing

Update after comment

---

You also you need to register a binder that will convert your Organization, roughly something like

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Organization.class,
            new PropertyEditorSupport() {

                @Override
                public void setAsText(String text) {
                    Organization organization = dao.find(Organization.class,
                            Integer.parseInt(text));
                    setValue(organization);
                }
            });
}
```

`dao.find(Organization.class, Integer.parseInt(text));` is a meta code of course

Comment: Now I am getting `nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.sprhib.model.Team.organization`. I walked through SO answers regarding this issue but still have no idea what is wrong with my code.

Comment: One more question, in `@InitBinder` in `setAsText` there is exception because for some unknown reason when empty string is passed. Exception: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`